# How to insulate teammate's code with each other in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-2015

We are going to start a project in c#, and need every man in our team can only view and edit his own part of code(boss's need). I am new to TFS, so I am wondering if and how TFS can do that.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like an extremely dodgy setup, but you could go about this a few different ways. A new Collection per person, a new Team Project per person, a subfolder in your branch per person with security settings ($/Project/PaulsCode, $/Project/SamanthasCode etc.) and so on. You could even do it per file but micromanaging security permissions like that will be a nightmare.

Comment: Have you looked at security and access rights? Should be easy to set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a branch per developer and setup permissions appropriately if that is something you need or you don't have to setup these permissions at all and still have the per developer branches for code isolation if you later decide that isn't something you need.  This is how a lot of open source projects work on GitHub where you fork a repository which is equivalent to branching in TFS.  You would then merge back to the main branch when you are satisfied with a developers changes in their own branch.

So your team project may look like this:

```
$/Team Collection  
---Team Project  
------Main  
------Dev  
---------Developer A  
---------Developer B
```

So in the example above `Developer A` is a branch of Main.  I strongly recommend reading the Visual Studio ALM Rangers guide to branching and merging if you are new to TFS and branching/merging.  Here is a link to download pdfs:

https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases

Here is a stack overflow article where someone asks a similar question:

[Per developer branch in TFS feasible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214523/per-developer-branch-in-tfs-feasible)

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is like super secret NSA or military kind of stuff, this setup is **stupid** and you should find a better job with a saner boss. In any VCS, your boss will see who changed what. There is no need for such brutal source code partitioning, IMNSHO. In fact, it gets in the way of collaboration. Even if this is NSA/military kind of stuff, some trust should be there because you should already be vetted as acceptable to see/develop the secret stuff.